# A client error (UnknownParameter) occurred when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress operation: The parameter CidrIp is not recognized

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

i am trying to create a outbound rule for a security group using aws cli. i used the following command

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-egress --cli-input-json file://auth_sec_grp_egress1.json
```

**which gave me error:**

```
A client error (UnknownParameter) occurred when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress operation: The parameter CidrIp is not recognized
```

The input json file **auth_sec_grp_egress1.json** is

```
{
    "DryRun": false, 
    "GroupId": "sg-99b2f2fd", 
    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
    "FromPort": 123, 
    "ToPort": 123, 
    "CidrIp": "172.24.102.126/32"
}
```

i looked at [AWS documetation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html) for the error code UnknownParameter , which says

> An unknown or unrecognized parameter was supplied. Requests
>   that could cause this error include supplying a misspelled parameter
>   or a parameter that is not supported for the specified API version.

but the json i am supplying as input is generated by the command

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-egress --generate-cli-skeleton > auth_sec_grp_egress1.json
```

i am working with **aws cli version - aws-cli/1.7.22 Python/2.7.9 Windows/7**

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with `--ip-permissions/IpPermissions`

```
{
    "DryRun": false, 
    "GroupId": "sg-99b2f2fd",
    "IpPermissions": [
        {
            "IpProtocol": "tcp",
            "FromPort": 123,
            "ToPort": 123,
            "IpRanges": [
                {
                  "CidrIp": "172.24.102.126/32"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get `The specified rule does not exist in this security group.` instead (I'm trying to remove a single CIDR range from the rule, not the entire rule...) (I can't add a new one - the group is full, which is why I'm trying to remove some ranges)

Answer (score 0):

**The TuxLife's answer was right. I don't know why it was downvoted :-/**  I will add my contribution about the Java SDK, because I was getting the same error.

I was trying to revoke a SecurityGroup's egress rule using the Java SDK.

```
ec2.revokeSecurityGroupEgress(new RevokeSecurityGroupEgressRequest()
     .withGroupId(id)
     .withCidrIp("0.0.0.0/0");
```

I was getting the same error about CidrIp. It seems that way to do it is wrong. I still don't know why, but I moved the CidrIp parameter to the IpPermissions / IpRanges and it worked.

```
ec2.revokeSecurityGroupEgress(new RevokeSecurityGroupEgressRequest()
     .withGroupId(id)
     .withIpPermissions(new ArrayList<IpPermission>() {{
         this.add(new IpPermission()
                 .withIpRanges(new ArrayList<String>() {{
                     this.add("0.0.0.0/0"); 
                 }})
                 .withIpProtocol("-1"));
     }}));
```